# Python convert a string to a logic operator

Tags: python, logical-operators, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, string-conversion

For example, if I have an expression like

`x=True or True`

if I evaluate in the shell the result is True

```
print(x)
x=True
```

So now I want to convert a string or an input to direct to that logic expression like

`x=raw_input('Please give an expression:')`

I know that the expression is a string so how to convert that string to a logic expression?

```
print(x)
x="True or True"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function:

```
print eval(x)
```

Note that you [must be cautious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/2670792) while using it.

**Edit:**

As @PriyankPatel mentioned, another way would be using [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec_stmt):

```
exec("print " + x)
```

Comment: `exec 'print True or True'` is this what u want ?